# mysql query to show everything that does not join :)

Tags: mysql

Imagine two tables that both have a common ID field that joins two tables together.

Lets call them Table1 and Table2.

Table1 joins Table2 on the field ID.

How do I get all results on Table2 that has an ID that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guessing you need one of these

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN LEFT table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table2.id IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN LEFT table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from Table2 where ID not in (select ID from Table1)
```

or

```
select * from (select * from Table1 right join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID) where foo is NULL
```

in which `foo` must be a column from Table1 that does not exist in Table2 and is never null in Table1.

EDIT: whoops, you can actually use ID as foo, as long as you qualify it with the table names:

```
select * from Table1.ID right join Table2.ID where Table1.ID is NULL
```

As explained here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Also interesting:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html is that you want?!

```
mysql> select name, phone, selling 

from Table2 join Table1 

on Table2.pid = Table1.pid;
```

Or you want:

```
mysql> select *

from Table2 

where Table2.pid is not null;
```